# Esconder código JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou há um tempo tentando descobrir se existe alguma maneira de esconder o código fonte JavaScript de acesso direto. Há alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Há diversas técnicas, mas não há como esconder pois o browser precisa compilar o código de qualquer forma..
O que pode fazer é obfuscar o código, o que também não garante proteção, mas pelo menos dificultará cópias.

Comment: Dependendo do motivo pelo qual você quer esconder (para não ser copiado, para não explorarem brechas, etc) você pode usar outros tipos de soluções, como por o código no servidor, ofuscar e *minificar* o JavaScript, etc. Mas tudo depende do caso. E se tratando de *client-side*, **não** existe um método 100% eficaz para "esconder" o JavaScript do usuário.

Comment: Caro amigo experimente utilizar Encrypt HTML Pro, acredito que irá atender suas necessidades.

Comment: É  impossível esconder. Você pode até fazer um tipo criptografia. Mais sempre tem alguém para descriptografar.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Diogo, o mais que pode fazer é atrapalhar quem quer ver o código fonte mas nunca vai poder escondê-lo na totalidade.

Pode fazer este código:

```
var a = "Hello World!";
function MsgBox(msg){
    alert(msg+"\n"+a);
}
MsgBox("OK");
```

aparecer assim:

```
var _0x8e48 = ["\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C\x64\x21", "\x0A", "\x4F\x4B"];
var a = _0x8e48[0];

function MsgBox(_0xab5dx3) {
    alert(_0xab5dx3 + _0x8e48[1] + a);
};
MsgBox(_0x8e48[2]);
```

ou somente

```
var a = "Hello World!";
function B(c){
    alert(c+"\n"+a);
}
B("OK");
```

Mas o utilizador pode sempre encontrar o código e decifrá-lo. Se o browser o consegue usar, o utilizador pode ver e tentar decifrar.

Answer (score 8):

Eu procurei diversas soluções na internet em inglês usando o termo "javascript obfuscator" e achei algumas soluções excelentes, porém pagas e bem caras (ainda mais para brasileiros que pagam o serviço em dólares).

Entretanto a empresa não queria pagar pela ferramenta, e eu acabei achando uma no github https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator

Dá pra usar a versão online também: https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/ e o melhor: é grátis e open-source.

---

Edit: por exemplo, se pegarmos o código que o @Sério postou na outra resposta:

```js
    var a = "Hello World!";
    function MsgBox(msg){
        alert(msg+"\n"+a);
    }
    MsgBox("OK");
```

E usarmos na [ferramenta acima](https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/), ele fica completamente ilegível e também protegido contra modificações. Se alguém tentar formatá-lo (colocar quebra de linhas, renomear variáveis ou funções, remover códigos, etc) usando um [javascript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) da vida, ele para de funcionar.

```js
var _0x3102=['\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21'];(function(_0x4d8cba,_0x14ad3c){var _0x52efb3=function(_0x1380af){while(--_0x1380af){_0x4d8cba['\x70\x75\x73\x68'](_0x4d8cba['\x73\x68\x69\x66\x74']());}};var _0x4fa633=function(){var _0x189275={'\x64\x61\x74\x61':{'\x6b\x65\x79':'\x63\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65','\x76\x61\x6c\x75\x65':'\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x6f\x75\x74'},'\x73\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65':function(_0x11387e,_0x173a51,_0x6a0123,_0xea9d6f){_0xea9d6f=_0xea9d6f||{};var _0xb46af2=_0x173a51+'\x3d'+_0x6a0123;var _0x5b1c00=0x0;for(var _0x5b1c00=0x0,_0x24424e=_0x11387e['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];_0x5b1c00<_0x24424e;_0x5b1c00++){var _0x4668d5=_0x11387e[_0x5b1c00];_0xb46af2+='\x3b\x20'+_0x4668d5;var _0x1001b3=_0x11387e[_0x4668d5];_0x11387e['\x70\x75\x73\x68'](_0x1001b3);_0x24424e=_0x11387e['\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68'];if(_0x1001b3!==!![]){_0xb46af2+='\x3d'+_0x1001b3;}}_0xea9d6f['\x63\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']=_0xb46af2;},'\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65':function(){return'\x64\x65\x76';},'\x67\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65':function(_0x386eb1,_0x29953b){_0x386eb1=_0x386eb1||function(_0x57ca6e){return _0x57ca6e;};var _0x32368d=_0x386eb1(new RegExp('\x28\x3f\x3a\x5e\x7c\x3b\x20\x29'+_0x29953b['\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65'](/([.$?*|{}()[]\/+^])/g,'\x24\x31')+'\x3d\x28\x5b\x5e\x3b\x5d\x2a\x29'));var _0x5c72b4=function(_0x258f31,_0x5426ba){_0x258f31(++_0x5426ba);};_0x5c72b4(_0x52efb3,_0x14ad3c);return _0x32368d?decodeURIComponent(_0x32368d[0x1]):undefined;}};var _0x3503fd=function(){var _0x2fcea3=new RegExp('\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x5c\x29\x20\x2a\x7b\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x2e\x2b\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x3b\x3f\x20\x2a\x7d');return _0x2fcea3['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0x189275['\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};_0x189275['\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']=_0x3503fd;var _0x4b2645='';var _0x2e4dc3=_0x189275['\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']();if(!_0x2e4dc3){_0x189275['\x73\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65'](['\x2a'],'\x63\x6f\x75\x6e\x74\x65\x72',0x1);}else if(_0x2e4dc3){_0x4b2645=_0x189275['\x67\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65'](null,'\x63\x6f\x75\x6e\x74\x65\x72');}else{_0x189275['\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x43\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65']();}};_0x4fa633();}(_0x3102,0xe5));var _0x4315=function(_0x7fe901,_0x45be0f){var _0x7fe901=parseInt(_0x7fe901,0x10);var _0xfb3ffb=_0x3102[_0x7fe901];return _0xfb3ffb;};var a=_0x4315('0x0');function MsgBox(_0x58908a){var _0x2bc273=function(){var _0x5e0360=!![];return function(_0x4f1bad,_0x575402){var _0x4fa53a=_0x5e0360?function(){if(_0x575402){var _0x205ab8=_0x575402['\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x79'](_0x4f1bad,arguments);_0x575402=null;return _0x205ab8;}}:function(){};_0x5e0360=![];return _0x4fa53a;};}();var _0x113342=_0x2bc273(this,function(){var _0x564997=function(){return'\x64\x65\x76';},_0x7cc57a=function(){return'\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77';};var _0x4ebdda=function(){var _0x45b262=new RegExp('\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x5c\x29\x20\x2a\x7b\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x2e\x2b\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x3b\x3f\x20\x2a\x7d');return!_0x45b262['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0x564997['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};var _0x30b472=function(){var _0x1b46dc=new RegExp('\x28\x5c\x5c\x5b\x78\x7c\x75\x5d\x28\x5c\x77\x29\x7b\x32\x2c\x34\x7d\x29\x2b');return _0x1b46dc['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0x7cc57a['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};var _0x105955=function(_0x486df9){var _0x4c7fc5=~-0x1>>0x1+0xff%0x0;if(_0x486df9['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']('\x69'===_0x4c7fc5)){_0x21396d(_0x486df9);}};var _0x21396d=function(_0x5f17fe){var _0x7ba70c=~-0x4>>0x1+0xff%0x0;if(_0x5f17fe['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']((!![]+'')[0x3])!==_0x7ba70c){_0x105955(_0x5f17fe);}};if(!_0x4ebdda()){if(!_0x30b472()){_0x105955('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');}else{_0x105955('\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66');}}else{_0x105955('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');}});_0x113342();alert(_0x58908a+'\x0a'+a);}MsgBox('\x4f\x4b');
```

Claro que como o exemplo de código que foi obfuscado é muito pequeno, a obfuscação ficou muito maior. Numa base de código maior, o código obfuscado não vai ficar proporcionalmente tão grande.

Comment: Tem esse daqui que é mais agressivo, mas o código fica muito maior: http://www.jsfuck.com/

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu tinha testado esse também, mas existem sites que revertem a obfuscação. O outro de que citei na resposta não achei como reverter.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar [este site](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) para "comprimir" seu código JavaScript, se quiser obfuscar o código, marque as opção "Base62 encode".

Lembrando que não existe um jeito de você esconder completamente seu JavaScript, sempre vai ter alguém que conhece mais do que um usuário normal e vai saber o que você está usando pra obfuscar o código.

Answer (score 4):

Como você não pode deixar de fornecer código JavaScript válido é preciso atacar o problema doutra perspetiva: como tornar o meu código o mais desinteressante possível.

Muita gente entende a "minificação" como uma técnica de "proteção" mas esta pretende apenas minimizar a quantidade de bytes trocados entre cliente e servidor, deixando a lógica ainda exposta.

A técnica que melhor satisfaz a sua necessidade é realmente a ofuscação, no entanto, para que seja um recurso válido, é preciso que seja refinada: se você testar a solução do @gcarvalho97 verá que é possível voltar facilmente ao seu código original.

Se você procurar no Google por JavaScript Obfuscator verá várias opções.
O [segundo resultado](https://jscrambler.com/) pareceu-me interessante pois oferece proteções como obrigar seu código a executar apenas para certos domínios.

Nenhum obfuscator lhe poderá dar 100% de garantias, mas lhe dará vantagem, desencorajando terceiros de copiarem seu código/lógica.