# Esconder o código fonte HTML da página

Tags: javascript, html

É possível esconder o código fonte da página? Pergunto porque o Twitter parece usar essa técnica. Vejam:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Twitter</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  a {
    color: #1da1f2;
  }
  svg {
    color: #1da1f2;
    display: block;
    fill: currentcolor;
    height: 21px;
    margin: 13px auto;
    width: 24px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>      
      <center>Se você não for redirecionado em breve, <a href="/">use este link</a>.</center>
    </noscript>
    <script nonce="+S++B3GsGLtBoFsjmI2+Pg==">
       document.cookie = "app_shell_visited=1;path=/;max-age=5";
       location.replace(location.href.split("#")[0]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: consigo ver normalmente o código fonte do twitter, quando usado a ferramenta de desenvolvedor, porém quando se ve o código fonte da pagina `CTRL+U` não aparece todo o código pois os elementos do twitter são carregados após o carregamento da pagina, você pode notar isso ao dar `F5` (recarregar a página)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Esconder código JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25119/esconder-c%c3%b3digo-js)

Comment: Colega, não é duplicata. A dúvida do outro colega é esconder JS e no meu é o HTML inteiro conforme ocorre no Twitter (sem a ferramenta do desenvolvedor) e sim vendo diretamente o código fonte.

Answer (score 1):

É possível esconder partes relevantes da lógica por trás de uma pagina usando uma linguagem server-side como o PHP. Com o PHP, por exemplo, você não conseguirá ver coisas como o código usado para fazer o login em uma página ou a função que dá acesso ao saldo de uma conta bancária. Mas sempre haverá algum HTML para ser exibido no navegador(que são os elementos com os quais o usuário pode intaragir), desta forma então, algum código HTML é sempre visível.